# How to layout workspace with CSS

Tags: html, css

I've created the following diagram of how i would like my UI to look:
[image: UI]

but i just can't get it to behave the way I want to using css.

I've tried to build it with CSS Grids, but instead of overflowing it's expanding beyond the max-width.

How would I do i contrain the app to 100vh or what other approaches would work?

Comment: What `max-width` do you have given? ;)

Comment: I don't think I have any `max-width` but I do set the `width` of the body to `100vw`.

Comment: Perhaps you try to give `html, body {margin:0;padding:0}` and `max-width:100%;max-height:100%`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS-Grid is what you want here. Just specify the grid-container height as `100vh`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto auto 1fr 1fr;
  height: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  gap: .25em;
}

.nav {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 1em;
}

main {
  grid-row: 2 / span 3;
  background: green;
}

.controls {
  background: lightgrey;
  padding: .5em;
}

.scroll {
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.h {
  height: 500px;
  background: linear-gradient(red, blue);
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="nav">Navbar</div>
  <main>Main</main>
  <div class="controls">Controls</div>
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="h"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="scroll">
    <div class="h"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dude you are a wizard, I couldn't figure this out for days, and you just come by and figure it out instantly, thanks!

Comment: Years of practice. ☺